# ADO.NET sql client. Отображается кириллица как - Çàãàçàííîñü

Tags: wpf

При считывании данных из базы "ms SQL server" значения кириллицей отображаются неверно, например, ????? Çàãàçîâàííîñòü ?? ????

Если использовать “SQL Server Management Studio”, все это выводится в нормальном виде. Изменять базу нельзя.

Что надо сделать?

```
         string connectString =@"Integrated Security = SSPI; pooling=false; Initial Catalog =F:\ARCHIVEMANAGER\ALARMLOGGING\ASU_DMPC-HMI_ALG_201207012000_201207031825.MDF; Data Source =FLORES\sqlexpress;"
     string strSelect = "SELECT  Text3, AckType, ServerID  FROM   [AlgViewRUS_ID] WHERE  [Text3] LIKE 'кост%'";


         SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter( strSelect, connectString );
         DataSet  _ds = new DataSet();
         dataAdapter1.Fill( _ds, AlgViewRUS_ID );

         datagrid1.ItemsSource = _ds.Tables[AlgViewRUS_ID].DefaultView;
```

Comment: Указать правильную кодировку?

Comment: не подскажете как?

Comment: это не помогаетCultureInfo myCultureInfo = new CultureInfo( "en-US" );
                 _ds.Locale = myCultureInfo;